# Dynamically populating a template with Angular 4 / 5

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5

Our application layout features a toolbar and the actual contents area. Since the toolbar has a somewhat complex DOM structure we have decided to create a component out of it.

We could reuse this component on each page, but the toolbar position is actually not next to the contents (some other components are in between). So we would rather place the toolbar once in the parent page component and just declare the toolbar contents on each page as necessary.

```
<app>
    <toolbar>
        <ng-container #toolbar></ng-container>
    </toolbar>

    <some unrelated component>...</some unrelated component>

    <content>
        <ng-template #tbcontent>
            <button>Click me!</button>
        </ng-template>
        <p>Actual page content!</p>
    </content>
</app>
```

Thus in the example above we would take the contents in `#tbcontent` and place them within `#toolbar`, effectively rendering something like this:

```
<app>
    <toolbar>
        <button>Click me!</button>
    </toolbar>

    <some unrelated component>...</some unrelated component>

    <content>
        <p>Actual page content!</p>
    </content>
</app>
```

We have tried querying both the `#toolbar` and the `#tbcontent` nodes from the root `AppComponent` using `@ViewChild` (code has been simplified for the sake of clarity):

```
@Component({
    /* ... */
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
    @ViewChild("tbcontent") tbcontent: TemplateRef<any>;
    @ViewChild("toolbar", {read: ViewContainerRef}) toolbar: ViewContainerRef;

    /* ... */

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        console.log('ngAfterViewInit');
        console.log(this.tbcontent);
        console.log(this.toolbar);
        this.toolbar.createEmbeddedView(this.tbcontent);
    }
}
```

But both references are `undefined`. Is there a way to properly access the elements? Is this actually a bad practice, and maybe there is a better way to achieve the same result?

**Update:** @martin-nuc 's kindly suggested using `*ngTemplateOutlet`, which seems to do the trick but only when the node that is copied lives within the same component. Here's a JSFiddle showing this:

https://jsfiddle.net/carlosafonso/k3oq56oq/3/

Thank you.

Comment: `<content>` is also a component?

Comment: Yes, it is, although quite a dummy one most of the time (just containing the <router-outlet> tag).

Comment: Can you define template outside of `<content>`? Just to be sure. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you define template it's not inserted into DOM. You need to use some directive to insert it to DOM.

Also `ng-container` is basically just a placeholder for some content but it's not rendered into DOM.

I think what you are trying to do is

```
<toolbar>
  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="tbcontent"></ng-container>
</toolbar>
```

EDIT: The questions was how to display template from child component in a parent component. I basically passed template as output from the child component. Here is how to achieve it.

Parent component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  template: `
    <div class="container">
      <toolbar>
         <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="toolbarContent"></ng-container>       
      </toolbar>
      <hr/>
      <content (toolbarLoaded)="displayToolbar($event)"></content>
    </div>
  `,
})
class AppComponent {

  constructor() {
  }

  displayToolbar($event) {
    this.toolbarContent = $event;
  }
}
```

Child component with toolbar template:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'content',
  template: `
    <ng-template #tb>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Content-specific action</button>
    </ng-template>
    <p>These are the page contents.</p>
  `
})
class ContentComponent {
  @Output() toolbarLoaded = new EventEmitter<any>();
  @ViewChild('tb') tb;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    // arrow function dont work in jsfiddle somehow :(
    let that = this;
    // we need timeout to avoid Expression had changed after it was checked (https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6005)
    setTimeout(() => {
        that.toolbarLoaded.emit(that.tb);
    }, 0);
  }
}
```

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fdv1tesr/3/

Comment: This seems to work if `#tbcontent` is also inside `<toolbar>`, but not if it's inside a sibling component.

I created this fiddle with the working configuration. If the `#tbcontent` node is moved to the `<content>` 
 template then the button does not appear in the toolbar:

https://jsfiddle.net/carlosafonso/k3oq56oq/2/

Comment: @cafonso `we would rather place the toolbar once in the parent page component and just declare the toolbar contents on each page as necessary.` - do you mean that you want to define `tbcontent` in the child component (`<content>`) but use it in parent component (`<app>`)?

Comment: Yes, because the buttons within the toolbar depend on the actual page that's being displayed.

For example, a list of users would show a button to create a new user, but the new user form would display a button to go back. This is why declaring the toolbar contents should, in my opinion, be done within the content itself.

Comment: @cafonso Sorry I misunderstood the question.

Comment: I have updated the jsfiddle sample to show how the toolbar buttons would be ideally declared, but as you can see they do not show up in the target placeholder: https://jsfiddle.net/carlosafonso/k3oq56oq/3/

Comment: Understand. I will try to figure it out.

Comment: @cafonso did it help?

Comment: didn't have the chance yet to give it a try, I'll keep you updated as soon as I do. Thanks!

Comment: Finally got the chance to test this. This does indeed work. Thank you!